# Entity Command Execution Exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I get Entity Command Execution Exception while compiling. Same line of code works fine somewhere else, but in place I need it returns this exception.

```
//Working fine here!
Questionnaire questionnaireeeee = context.Set<Questionnaire>().Include(q => q.QuestionnaireQuestions.Single(q => q.ID == 1);
//need to see who is logged in, administrator or professor
 string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
//...
if(User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
{
    //grouping subject instances by same semester
    var subjectInstancesBySemester = from subjectInstances in context.SubjectInstances group subjectInstances by subjectInstances.Semester;
    foreach (var subjectInstancesGroup in subjectInstancesBySemester)
    {
         // getting questionnaire related to this semester
         if(subjectInstancesGroup.Key.QuestionnaireID != null)
         {
        //Exception is here!
             Questionnaire questionnaire = context.Set<Questionnaire>().Include(q => q.QuestionnaireQuestions).Single(q => q.ID == (int) subjectInstancesGroup.Key.QuestionnaireID);
             //...
         }
    }
}
```

And I checked with breakpoint, subjectInstancesGroup.Key.QuestionnaireID has value 1, and there is row in table Questionnaire with ID of 1. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity framework will probably not be able to compile the expression tree you're giving him.

Does adding .ToArray() solve the problem?

```
var subjectInstancesBySemester = 
       from subjectInstances in context.SubjectInstances 
       group subjectInstances by subjectInstances.Semester;

foreach (var subjectInstancesGroup in subjectInstancesBySemester.ToArray())
{
     // getting questionnaire related to this semester
     if(subjectInstancesGroup.Key.QuestionnaireID != null)
     {
         var questionnaireId = (int) subjectInstancesGroup.Key.QuestionnaireID;
         Questionnaire questionnaire = context.Set<Questionnaire>().Include(q => 
                  q.QuestionnaireQuestions).Single(q => q.ID == questionnaireId);
         //...
     }
}
```

By adding .ToArray() a query is performed against the database. Entity framework now does not need to compile this in a more complicated query. As your iterating anyhow over the complete returnset I don't think this will be a problem.